# Batch File For Loop Only Counts To 8

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have this script that looks at every file in a folder and attempts to determine the last file name in the directory, add 1 to it and create a new folder with that name. The naming convention is J21-001-JobName, J21-002-JobName etc.

```
FOR /F %%F in ('dir /b /ad /on C:\Jobs\2021\*') DO (
SET fname=%%~nxF
SET pname=!fname:~4,3%!
SET /A last = pname+1
ECHO !last!
SET zeros=000!last!
SET finalname=!zeros:~-3!
)
```

I capture the folder name, reduce it to just the numbers (i.e. 001), add 1 to it (i.e. 2), add the 0's back (i.e. 0002) and finally reduce the name to 3 digits (i.e. 002).

For some reason this works but only up until J21-008-JobName. After that there is a break down. ECHO !last! returns

```
1
2
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1
```

Yes 2 twice. Any ideas why I might be seeing this behavior? Thank you in advance!

Comment: From the help file for the `SET` command. **Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless
prefixed by 0x for hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers.
So 0x12 is the same as 18 is the same as 022. Please note that the octal
notation can be confusing: 08 and 09 are not valid numbers because 8 and
9 are not valid octal digits.**

Comment: `SET "pname=1000!fname:~4,3!"`, `set /A pname+=1` and `SET "zeros=!pname:~-3!` (and probably `set "finalname=!fname:~0,4!!zeros!!fname:~7!"`)

Comment: Thank you both! Squashman for explaining why and Stephan for helping me fix it.  `SET pname=1000!fname:~4,3%!` fixed my problem.